Single board computer for 24/7 runtime
I am looking for a single board computer that I can leave on for 24/7 at home. I have done some research and I found out that an option would be a Raspberry Pi or Orange Pi. Further I found a similar post but the specs. are quite different. This post
The board should run some light server tasks and a couple of other things. This board needs to have a couple of minimum specs (more is always welcome):

4GB ram
Quad core CPU
GUI (no command line only)
Gigabit ethernet
Preferably room for M.2 SSD. Micro SD is also OK
At least 1 USB 3.0
Reliable for 24/7 runtime

Are there any other reliable brands out there that have models that have at least the minimum specs I want?

Honestly your best bet is gonna be the raspberry pi 4 model it has everything your asking for and as well you can buy the M.2 Hat+ module so you can add your M.2 SSDs if you desire. You could also look at some Arduino stuff but that's usually not the same open-box experience you get with raspberry's. Truthfully you can't beat the single board raspberrypi's they are amazing single board, portable computers that dont require a bunch of extra work/non-sense.
Now if you're very techy and know how to reprogram logic boards it's possible in theory to use just about any board out of a laptop, tablet, phone, etc. and basically turn them into a raspberry but like I said a lot more work and headache when you could buy a Pi for 35$
